# Prove every continuous $f$ can be written as $g-h$ where $g,h$ are continuous, non-negative functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

let $f$ be a continuous function.  I want to show that $\exists$ continuous non-negative functions $g$ and $h$ such that $f = g - h$.

My attempt:
define 
$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x), & \text{for $x$ such that $f(x)>0$} \\
0, & \text{for $x$ such that $f(x)\leq 0$}
\end{cases}$$
and 
$$h(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{for $x$ such that $f(x)\geq0$} \\
-f(x), & \text{for $x$ such that $f(x)<0$}
\end{cases}$$
The trouble I was having was in showing that $g$ is in fact continuous.  This was what I tried:

let $a \in \mathbb{R}$.  Suppose $a$ is such that $f(a)>0$.  Then since $f$ is continuous, $\exists \delta_0 >0$ such that $\forall x: |x-a|<\delta_0 \implies f(x)>0$.  Then within this delta interval, $g(x)=f(x)$ and so it can be shown that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=f(a)=g(a)$. Hence $g$ is continuous for $a$ such that $f(a)>0$

How do I finish off?  I think I'm most confused about showing continuity for piecewise functions like these.

Comment: Ah yes, this is quite nice - I didn't think of this.  Either way, I'm still wondering how to prove that such a piecewise function is continuous, as I feel it would be a useful trick to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f={\vert f\vert +f \over 2}+{-\vert f\vert+f \over 2}$

Comment: How do you think of something like this?  Does it just come with experience?

Comment: You are just making the first function equal to $f(x)$ when $f(x)>0$ and zero otherwise, and the second function equal to $f(x)$ when $f(x)<0$ and zero otherwise. Surely that is an obvious thing to try?